# Question about setter and calling MyClass()

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class like this:

```
class A:
    b = ""
    @property
    some_property(self):
        raise Error()

    @some_property.setter
    def some_property(self, some_property_var)
        self.b = some_property_var
```

and i want to do A(some_property='A'), but i can't because

> TypeError: A() takes no arguments

. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as correct if you think I answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a better example of how to demonstrate what you are trying to do;

```
#set a property in a class in python
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    @age.setter
    def age(self, age):
        self._age = age
        
p = Person("John", 36)
```

So in your case;

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, b):
        self._b = b
a = A(1)
print(a.b)
```

Based on your comments;

```
#create a class that takes keyword arguments
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
a = A(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: I was actually looking into miguels tutorial:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/models.py

He has a User there with a password attribute and in the tests he instantiates them like this User(password='test') and it's somehow working. There is no self.b = b there and the property doesn't return anything.

Comment: See my update please